# Cloudfare en Python intermitente

Tags: python, requests

estoy raspando una página web de artículos.
Resulta que el programa se ejecuta sin problema alguno hasta cierto punto donde salta la protección de Cloudfare. Si paro la ejecución y la inicio de manera inmediata (Todo de forma manual), la protección desaparece y la ejecución continúa normalmente hasta que pasan unos minutos y la protección vuelve a saltar.

¿Existe alguna forma de "Resetear" la ejecución mediante código sin tener que reiniciar el proceso completo? Intenté con un while, pero la protección dura al menos unos 30 minutos, no es inmediato como al reiniciar el proceso de manera manual.

Cabe destacar que estoy utilizando requests+bs4, por lo que imagino, tal vez la ip tenga algo que ver, la verdad no soy muy conocedor y es por eso vengo aquí.

Gracias por leer.

Comment: podrías agregar lo que tienes?

Comment: Crea una tabla en la BBDD con las páginas a visitar. En cada ejecución, selecciona al azar una página no visitada, raspala, marcala como visitada y termina la ejecución. Luego crea un proceso regular (cron) que ejecute el raspador a los intervalos/horarios deseados.